# File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 1 phone balance = 20 ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

phone balance = 20
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

phone balance = 20
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a descriptive title (e.g. "Syntax Error at Python variable name") and describing your problem before you post the code. That way, others can learn from it as well. See this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please specify what are you trying to do and what problems are you facing. From your question I think you are trying to create a variable "phone balance" but you cannot create a variable with spaces. Learn about python variable naming.

Answer (score -2):

Variable names in Python may only consist of upper case or lower case characters, numbers and underscores. Here are some examples for valid variable names:

- `balance`
- `phone_balance`
- `PHONE_VERSION`
- `balance2`

However, those examples won't work:

- `phone balance`: Syntax Error (no space allowed)
- `phone!balance`: Syntax Error (no special characters allowed)

Remove the space from your variable name and try it again.